# Proving $D(G) ≤ w(1 + (t − 1) \log w) $

Tags: group-theory, inequality, proof-explanation, abelian-groups

Given,$$D(G) ≤ \exp(G)(1 + \log(|G|/\exp(G))),$$ where $D(G)$ is Davenport's constant, for any finite Abelian group $G$. Let the cyclic group of the order $w$  is denoted by  $C_w$.

If $$  g_1, \dots, g_k \in  C_w^t,    k ≥ tw \log(w), G = C_w^t,$$ and $$\exp(G) = w,$$ then how the below inequality holds?

$$D(G) ≤ w(1 + (t − 1) \log w) ≤ tw \log w$$

Because, $\exp(G)(1 + \log(|G|/\exp(G))) = w (1+\log (k/w)) > w (1+\log (tw \log(w)/w)) = w (1+\log (t \log(w))) =  w (1+\log\log(w^t))$

**Source:**

[image]

Comment: If you're citing a paper or a book, you should probably mention what that paper/book is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $G$ is $t$-th Cartesian power of $C_w$, so $|G|=w^t$, $\exp (G)=w$, therefore

$$\exp(G)(1 + \log(|G|/\exp(G))) = w (1+\log (w^{t-1}))= w (1+(t-1)\log w)\le tw\log w,$$

for $w>2$, because in this case $t\log w\ge\log w\ge 1$.

Comment: Hi! thanks for your help but could you plz add to the answer why We have $|G|=w^t$?

Comment: @ConsiderNon-TrivialCases Done.

Comment: @ConsiderNon-TrivialCases Yes, $X^t$ is a standard notation for a $t$-th Cartesian power of a set $X$.

Comment: Yes I got it just after the comment I am goingt to award the bounty but it takes atleast 24 hour after declaration.... btw $C_w^t$ looks like a product of cyclic group in that case is its element is a $t$-tupple having elements of $C_w$ ?  if possible plz provide an example how it looks like, thanks.

Comment: @ConsiderNon-TrivialCases For instance, if $C_3=\{e,g,g^2\}$ then $C_3^2=\{(e,e), (e,g), (e,g^2), (g,e), (g,g), (g,g^2), (g^2,e), (g^2,g), (g^2,g^2) \}$.